# Recursive directory listing

Tags: php, recursion, file-system

I'm trying to optimize performance for recursive directory listing with some exceptions:

```
function listdir($basedir) {
    global $root, $ignore_dirs, $ignore_files, $filetypes, $ignore_starts_with;
        if ($handle = @opendir($basedir)) { 
            while (false !== ($fn = readdir($handle))) { 
                if ($fn != '.' && $fn != '..') {

                    $s = true;
                    foreach ($ignore_starts_with as $pre) if (strpos($fn, $pre) === 0) $s = false;

                    $dir = $basedir."/".$fn;
                    if ($s && is_dir($dir) && !in_array($fn, $ignore_dirs)) {
                        listdir($dir);
                    } else {

                        if ($s && !in_array($fn,$ignore_files) && preg_match("/[^.\/].+\.($filetypes)$/",$dir,$fname)) printlink($fname[0]);
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        closedir($handle); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Optimize how?  Where is the bottleneck?  What have your profiling results shown?

Comment: im not shire about foreach construction, and many if's

Comment: Well, I would prove that is actually a bottleneck before potentially wasting time optimizing them out (if that's even possible).  For example, if 98% of your time is spent doing I/O then removing an if statement or a loop is pointless.  That said, your `$s` variable will only hold the *last* assignment, so you may as well just break out of it the first time that condition is met.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I'd use [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://www.php.net/~helly/php/ext/spl/classRecursiveDirectoryIterator.html), removed globals and corrected formatting.

Then used Xdebug + CacheGrind to try different versions.